# How to keep the file size small in PhoneGap apps? what compression should be used to store the files in filesystem?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

We are developing a PhoneGap application (iOS & Android). That needs to store some  data in mobile database(SQLite) and some PDF/JPG files File system to make application working in offline mode.

We will download this data once the application has been installed. My question is, Which format we should use to store the PDF/JPG files in filesystem ? It is in Zip format? Any other compression ? Or No compression ?

Which one is recommended?

Comment: Are you aware that PDF/JPG files are already compressed?

Comment: No, I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any compression, save the files as they are in file system. Make sure you have appropriate file size ready before download(for eg: 100kb png images is enough for mobile). Make sure you keep your data safe here is a good link how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184492/best-way-to-secure-android-app-sensitive-data)