# Is there a way to safely save data so that players cannot change it?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Android game where I need to save the player's points, premium currency, and level.  The problem is that I want the information to be saved in the player's device, but I do not want them to be able to change it.  How would I go about writing integers to a file in such a way so that a player cannot find the file and easily change it?  Is it safe to store something, like premium currency, on the player's device, or do I need to make a database?

I'm using C# and Unity for my game, so I want something that is not JUST Android.  This way, I do not have to reprogram much in order to release it on another platform, such as iOS.

Also, I cannot really make a database because I have to rent one, and I have no money.  :3

Comment: 100% of unity developers use this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10395 it's very cheap, and the best.  you simply can't use ordinary PlayerPrefs, it's one of the ridiculous things about Unity that PlayerPrefs does not have even basic security.  Everyone just uses ACTK, enjoy

Comment: (of course you may need EVEN MORE security in many situations, usually server based.  be aware that is far from foolproof also, MITM attacks and spoofing are trivial to achieve.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trust the client's premium currency value (or any values the client stores, really) it can and will be exploited. You want to store those values on a server and have the client ask for them.

Comment: Thanks!  What would I do if the client does not have internet?

Comment: You could temporarily save the value so the client sees the value, but only allow purchase if they have a connection and the server can verify it's legitimate.

Comment: beginners should just use one of the silly currency systems out there, like "soomla" or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Without storing that data off device, how do you plan on refunding / reappointing players money in the event the file is lost? This post here [Best way to secure Android app sensitive Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184492/best-way-to-secure-android-app-sensitive-data) goes over the limitations of the linux filesystem on android and how a user with root will have access to pretty much any file. I would strongly suggest you find a free solution that can scale as you earn money with your app.(i.e Azure, amazon etc.)