# How to store cache data in encrypted format in android

Tags: caching, encryption

how could I store application cache data in encrypted format on user devices? Is there any way to secure my application cache data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to secure Android app sensitive Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184492/best-way-to-secure-android-app-sensitive-data)