# Is Firebase Config is secure for storing sensitive data?

Tags: android

I had stored my web service URLs in fire base remote config for security purpose. Is there any better way to secure URL.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Remote Configuration Policies

**Policies and limits**
Note the following policies:

Don't use Remote Config to make app updates that should require a user's authorization. This could cause your app to be perceived as untrustworthy.

> Don't store confidential data in Remote Config parameter keys or
>   parameter values. It is possible to decode any parameter keys or
>   values stored in the Remote Config settings for your project.

clearly mentioned in Documentation that it is not useful for sensitive data.

For Securing Sensitive data you should also read

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8184699/6236752

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please suggest me where to store sensitive data?

Comment: you are dynamically changing your urls by time?

Comment: No, my urls are static.

Comment: then store them in a private app directory.

Comment: Can you give me some example, how to use it? Is it secure in reverse engineering of apk?

Comment: for your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/8184699/6236752 read this answer and see in which category you fall.