# What is the best way to store sensitive data in android?

Tags: android, android-storage

My cyber-security team reports that I cannot store certificate or cookies in Internal storage. What is the best way to store these sensitive data in Android?

What are the best way to store these files without being compromised or lost sensitive information?

1. Go to /data/data/path/webview/Default/Session\ Storage and check the session being stored under log file.
2. Go to /data/data/path/webview/Default and check Request verification token being stored under cookies.
3. Check /data/data/path/files/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: You can check this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184492/best-way-to-secure-android-app-sensitive-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Encrypted Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) for storing sensitive information inside the app itself.